# How to authenticate to Azure AD B2C in Delphi desktop application using OAuth 2.0

Tags: azure, delphi, oauth-2.0, azure-ad-b2c

I would like to be able to use Azure AD B2C in my Delphi desktop application to authenticate users.    I am using the latest version of Delphi.  Has anyone successfully authenticated to Azure AD B2C in Delphi using OAuth 2.0?  Any sample code or application or advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's zero effort from your side for a specific programming problem.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a free code writing or translation service. 
 We're more than happy to help once you've made an effort to solve the problem yourself 
 and run into difficulties. When that happens, you can explain the problem you're having, 
 include the relevant portions of your code (and any original code) in the form of a 
 [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), 
 and ask a specific question related to that code, and we'll try to help.